# Tomcat installation on Synology DSM 7

Tags: spring, tomcat, nas

I would like to deploy a Spring application to a Synology NAS running DSM 7, but I don't see how to install Tomcat.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I just checked. Seems like the highest version of Tomcat supported by dsm is Tomcat v7. https://www.synology.com/en-us/dsm/packages/Tomcat7?os_ver=6.2. For version 6.2 that is. The search results for dsm v 7 shows no results whatsoever for tomcat ...
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3tCIe.jpg)

Comment: A bit tricky, but maybe home-brew could be an option to by-pass the regular installation process

Comment: hmmm ... https://www.synology.com/en-uk/products/status/EOL_announcement_for_synology_package_202105